# Accidentally published wrong InfoPath form! Missing data! HELP!

Tags: infopath, infopath-data-connections

We use SharePoint lists with InfoPath form templates for various lists.  When a user fills out the InfoPath form, it is submitted to its respective list.  Each list has columns published that pulls data from the submitted form.

On Friday, I published an incorrect (and very old) version of an InfoPath form to a list.  All of the columns are now blank.  When I open previously submitted forms from this list it just shows me a blank version of the incorrect form.

When i look at the last modified date for each form it shows the correct date, so I BELIEVE the data is still there, but it's not pulling up because it's using the incorrect version of the template.

How can I fix this?  I have tried to restore previous versions of the submitted forms but it just pulls up using the incorrect template and does not have any data.  Do I just re-publish the correct version of the template?  What other options do I have for restore?  Is there any way I can pull the data from SQL?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by publishing the original template and then re-opening each form to repopulate the data in all columns.